# Get first item from each category

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 5 categories:

Book, DVD, Rent, Buy, Sell

I use the following query to select the latest count of items.

```
public async Task<IList<Post>> GetRecentPostsAsync(int count)
{
    return await _db.Posts
        .Where(e => e.Published.HasValue && e.Published.Value <= DateTime.Today)
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.Published)
        .Take(count)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

My Post class looks like this:

```
public class Post
{
    #region Properties

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Published { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This returns my count of items. I want to make a new function where I get the most recently published item from the first 4 categories, so excluding the category Sell. It should return 4 items back.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [mre], simple class representing Posts with category. And initialisation. you don't need N categories just more than 1 with more than one item in each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you back a `List<Post>` with the last published `Post` in each category except "Sell":

```
return await _db.Posts
        .Where(x => x.Category != "Sell" && x.Published.HasValue && x.Published.Value <= DateTime.Today)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Published).Take(1))
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Nice and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't immediately understand the question. So, try that.

```
public async Task<IList<Post>> GetRecentPostsAsync()
        {            
            List<string> categories = new List<string> { "Book", "DVD", "Rent", "Buy" };
            List<Post> result = new List<Post>();

            foreach (string category in categories)
            {
                Post post = db.Posts.Where(e => e.Published.HasValue && e.Published.Value <= DateTime.Today && e.Category == category)
                    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Published)
                    .Take(1).First();
                result.Add(post);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: It now takes 1 item. I need it to take 1 item from every 4 categories, so 4 items in total.

Comment: As Krishna advised, you'd better create a category class or enumeration

Comment: You missed the category == e.category, but apart from that this works perfectly! I'll try Krishna's method now, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will give you the count by Category excluding Sell

```
public class PostCategory 
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IList<PostCategory>> GetRecentPostsAsync()
{
    return await _db.Posts
        .Where(e => e.Published.HasValue && e.Published.Value <= DateTime.Today && e.Category != "Sell")
        .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
        .Select(y => new { Category = y.Key, Count = y.Count() })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: This seems to give me the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Category, int Count>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<.Model.Domain.Post>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?"

But adding a cast just gives me another error

Comment: Yes, create a new class with Category and Count and return as list<newclass>

Comment: Alright, I created a new domain class PostCategory with string Category and int Count. How do I use that in this function?

Comment: Updated my post